# Require Reinstalling programs when Upgrade from Mac OS X 10.5.8 to Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, upgrade

So, when I upgrade to Snow Leopard from 10.5.8, do I need to reinstall all programes (especially the paid ones, like Adobe)?  Or the programs will automatically migrate to the new OS?

Answer (score 4):

They will not migrate, they will just stay there. Most will just work, those that don't work any more will need re-installation. But those are few.

Answer (score 1):

Most (if not all) of your applications should migrate over with the install and you should not have to reinstall them. When you launch Photoshop for the first time after upgrading it may run some 'maintenance' tasks before it will launch, but that should only be a once-off task and should not cause any troubles.